# JavaScript - React native wait for callback to execute and use its variables

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

this is my function where am calculating image's height and width, but I had to use react native's image. getSize`but this has a callback which a has a delay somehow and the return brock seems to execute before this image. getSize` finish.

```
 renderNode (node, index, siblings, parent, defaultRenderer) {
            let finalwidth ;
            let finalheight;
            if (node.name === 'img') {
              const a = node.attribs;

              Image.getSize(a.src, (width, height) => {

                let screenSize = Dimensions.get('window');
                let hRatio = screenSize.width / width;
                let vRatio = screenSize.height / height;
                let ratio = Math.max(hRatio, vRatio); 
                let rat = hRatio / vRatio;
                 finalwidth = parseInt(width * ratio);
                 finalheight = parseInt(height * ratio);

                alert(finalwidth + 'x' + finalheight) // they have values here

              })


             return ( 
               <Image
                key={index}
                source={{uri: a.src}}
                resizeMode={'stretch'}
                style={{
                  width: finalwidth,  //finalwidth is null here
                  height:finalheight,  //finalheight is null here
                  }}

                />
              );
            }
          }
```

Actually, I want to access the value of final width and final height in my return brock

Answer (score 1):

use setState() and set those values into state so that the component is rerendered when the data is updated

```
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={finalwidth : null, 
           finalheight: null
       }
    }

 renderNode (node, index, siblings, parent, defaultRenderer) {

            if (node.name === 'img') {
              const a = node.attribs;

              Image.getSize(a.src, (width, height) => {

                let screenSize = Dimensions.get('window');
                let hRatio = screenSize.width / width;
                let vRatio = screenSize.height / height;
                let ratio = Math.max(hRatio, vRatio); 
                let rat = hRatio / vRatio;
                 finalwidth = parseInt(width * ratio);
                 finalheight = parseInt(height * ratio);
                 this.setState({finalwidth, finalheight})
                alert(finalwidth + 'x' + finalheight) // they have values here

              })


             return ( 
               <Image
                key={index}
                source={{uri: a.src}}
                resizeMode={'stretch'}
                style={{
                  width: this.state.finalwidth,  //finalwidth from state
                  height: this.state.finalheight,  //finalheight from state
                  }}

                />
              );
            }
          }
```

Comment: oh sorry for not telling but i call that function `renderNode` during rendering and also i have used states and it still not working  `this.state.finalwidth` and `this.state.finaheight` are still null